# Computed value with argument in Svelte

Tags: svelte

In Vue, you can just define a method with an argument, and the return value of this method is recomputed whenever necessary.

In Svelte, I'm trying to do the same thing, but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I have:

```
<script>
    let date = 1;
    
    function selectDate(d) {
        date = d;
    }
    
    function isSelected(d) {
        return d === date;
    }
</script>

<div>
    {#each { length: 30 } as _, i}
        <div class:bold={isSelected(i)} on:click={() => selectDate(i)}>
            { i }
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    .bold {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

Whenever `date` is updated, I would like `isSelected`'s return value to be recomputed for every place it is called in the DOM. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to simplify this to `class:bold={date === i}` convert the calculation using a [reactive statement](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive) like this >> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/da7b533d667744eba5266770d9165d11?version=3.47.0)

```
<script>
    let date = 1;

    function selectDate(d) {
        date = d;
    }

    $: isSelected = (d) => {
        return d === date;
    }
</script>

<div>
    {#each { length: 30 } as _, i}
    <div class:bold={isSelected(i)} on:click={() => selectDate(i)}>
        { i }
    </div>
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    .bold {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    div {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to add the date as an argument, that way the function will be called again, if the date changes:

```html
<script>
    let date = 1;
    
    function selectDate(d) {
        date = d;
    }
    
    function isSelected(d, date) {
        return d === date;
    }
</script>

<div>
    {#each { length: 30 } as _, i}
        <button type=button
                class:bold={isSelected(i, date)}
                on:click={() => selectDate(i)}>
            { i }
        </button>
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    .bold {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b26e8fab14a74c7b8218b1de09263c89?version=3.47.0)

(By the way, you should use a button if something can be clicked for accessibility reasons. It can be restyled as necessary or wrapped in additional  elements for layout purposes.)